# Adjust rows with the same value (e.g. date) to be in the same column in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a spreadsheet with columns, that has values (e.g. dates) in the first row. There are many pairs of rows, that has dates in the first row with values assigned to them in the second row. Everything is clearly visible in screenshots.

How to adjust those values to the reference dates (from the first row)?

I was thinking about some VBA macro, but it's beyond my skills.

**Current State:**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/srhuj.png]

**Desired State:**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDqRX.png]

Comment: Still, maybe you've tried something? As you are new, please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, welcome! Please show us what you've tried, and we'll help you fix errors, but you'll find very few willing to write your code for you. If you're not sure where to start, you may try using the Macro Recorder to get the basics of moving the cells around, then figure out how to put some conditional code around it to determine what to move & how far.

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Comment: @Jeeped: it's not this case, there is no code in screenshot, and showing position of cells and data couldn't be possible using plain text

Comment: @FreeMan: I was not expecting written code but only ideas how to do it from people, who done it before. For example what function to use.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in answers not commenting and discussion:
of course, firstly you have to open file, etc. The most important part is searching.

```
' now copy all quotation
    sourceFile.Activate
    Range("A9:B5926").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

' paste all quotation in special place
    Range("A1500").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
           False, Transpose:=True

' close file
    sourceFile.Close

' search for date
    dateToSearch = CStr(Cells(1500, 1).Value2)
    Range("B1", Cells(1, 6000)).Select
    Set cellWithDate = Range("B1", Cells(1, 6000)).Find(What:=dateToSearch, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
' .Row .Column to get address parts
    columnNumOfPasting = cellWithDate.Column

' paste in right position
    Range("A1501", Cells(1501, 6000)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(numerLini, columnNumOfPasting).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
           False, Transpose:=False
' clear data in special place
    Range("A1500", Cells(1501, 6000)).Clear
```